# Set a marker over all other markers in Google Maps SDK iOS

Tags: ios, marker, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to place a marker, but when I do it, this marker is placed behind of some markers set before (and over some others as well). I want to set it over all the markers, but I didn't find any property (like z-index) to achieve this.

This is the part of the code where I set the marker that stays behind the others:

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.animated=YES;
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);
marker.map = mapView_;
```

and this is the result:

[image: Green marker is placed behind some blue markers and over other blue markers]

Is there any property or way to place the green marker over all blue markers? I'm using Google Maps SDK version 1.3.0.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is now supported via a `zIndex` property added to the `GMSOverlay` class in version 1.4.0. From the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases#version_140_-_july_2013):

> Added a `zIndex` property on all overlays. Z-Indexes are calculated in two groups: `GMSMarker`s and all other overlays.

Just set a high `zIndex` on your marker to have it drawn on top of all others. As stated by the property documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_overlay.html#a0e9871b40c30bb39f9a45dadaf7a0f75):

> Higher `zIndex` value overlays will be drawn on top of lower `zIndex` value tile layers and overlays.

The default `zIndex` for a marker is `0` (at least in the current SDK version - I haven't seen it documented, but it's easy to test and confirm), so if you're not setting the `zIndex` for most of your markers and have one that you want to place above all the others, all you need to do is:

```
yourGmsMarker.zIndex = 1;
```

Comment: If you want to put a marker onto another, put the previous zIndex below 1 ( say 0.8) , and then 1.0