# iOS How can I move googlemap marker to the front?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I added two marks on Google maps. Now the two markers are overlapping. I want the selected marker to be always in the front. That means when you select a marker this marker covers another marker. I looked at the Google maps development documentation, which does not provide the relevant API.

How can I do this?

[image: the two overlapped markers]

Comment: Have you tried re-adding the markers in a certain order?

Comment: I found the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808563/set-a-marker-over-all-other-markers-in-google-maps-sdk-ios  Still thanks for your answer @Sealos

Answer (score 4):

A simple resolution is using the propertie `zIndex`, just set to 1.

```
customMark.zIndex = 1
```

For more informations, you can see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker