# Current location blue point is showing under the marker

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have successfully integrated google map in my iOS app. But the issue is...

> Once I have added the marker on google map near to the current location then the current location blue dot hides behind the marker.

**I want the current location marker to be shown always on top of the other markers.**

How can I do that?

I have played with the `z-Index`property of the marker but did not succeed.

```
let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude-0.0005, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
marker.title = "ABC"
marker.snippet = "XYZ"
marker.map = self.mapView
//  marker.zIndex = 0.  <- did not work
```

[image]

Comment: have you try this.. `yourGmsMarker.zIndex = 1;` Link Reference.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808563/set-a-marker-over-all-other-markers-in-google-maps-sdk-ios

Comment: `yourGmsMarker.zIndex = 1` is for the marker that we need top of other marker. But I want the blue for to be top of all the other marker.

Comment: "The current location blue dot should be at the top of the all other marker." I want this. This is done in many other apps like trip advisor, etc.

Comment: @MahendraGP  May be you can add custom marker with blue dot and change it's zIndex to top

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya, yes that way it is possible but I want to manipulate the existing  blue dot of google map.

Comment: @MahendraGP did you find solution for the problem?

Comment: No, not yet. I am also searching for the same

Comment: @Mahendra have you find any solution?

Comment: No, The only way is to design custom marker and show on current location.

Comment: @Mahendra have you managed to find a solution? I've just run into a similar issue as you :/

Comment: No, I did not find any solution.

Comment: are you able to make the zIndex of the location bigger than the zIndex of the marker?